# data option out of *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have ionic3 app and have code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let m of inbox">
  <ion-avatar item-start>

    <img *ngIf="user.id != m.user_id" (click)="sendMessage(m.user_id)" [src]="m.avatar">
    <img *ngIf="user.id == m.user_id" [src]="m.avatar">

  </ion-avatar>
      <p>{{ m.username }} </p>
      <span style="position: absolute;bottom: 24px;">{{ m.content }}</span>
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col right text-right>
        <ion-note>
          {{ m.action  }} - {{ m.created_at | date:'dd/MM-yy HH:mm' }}
        </ion-note>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-item>
```

This (inbox) has a list of messages with some data. I also have function `sendMessage(m.user_id)` and this one works with m.user_id

I want show button out of this `*ngFor` like this:

```
<button ion-button medium color="btn-pink" block (click)="sendMessage()">besked</button>
```

but how I can access m.user_id?

Comment: where do you want to place the button?

Comment: after *ngFor ............

Comment: Ah, you'll have to run another loop in the <button> tag then.

<button *ngFor="let m of inbox" ion-button medium color="btn-pink" block (click)="sendMessage()">besked {{m.user_id}}</button>

Comment: but button will repeat and I thont whant this.

Comment: ah! I finally got what you mean. Let me write down an answer then.

Comment: btw, I forgot to ask, where do you need to access the m.user_id? In the html or in the component? Also, when you press the button, do you want to send all the messages inside inbox or just one specific message tracked by the m variable?

Comment: will be good in access in html, but in component will also clear for me. I am sending message inside this page in this repeat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153967/discussion-between-anjil-dhamala-and-gocha-gochitashvili).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this first of all you need to decide on clicking the button (sendMessage) for which user the acting will be the trigger. For this, you need to select the user from the list of n users. For this you can add some mechanism to select the particular user in your *ngFor loop (let say you introduce checkbox, or simply clicking on that particular user avatar). Then you can store the user id in some variable and then pass the variable in sendMessage function